# Gradle include dependencies of a dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Scenario**

I have two Android libraries:

- Library A
- Library B

Library B depends on Library A and includes it from its build.gradle.

My Android app needs to use Library B and some base classes from Library A. The only success I've had in doing this is including both libraries in my Android app's build.gradle and setting transitive to false.

**Question**:

Is there a way for me to only add Library B and have access to its dependency from my Android app?

---

**Android Studio**

```
Android Studio 3.1 Canary
Build #AI-171.4415322, built on October 24, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1012-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

**Gradle**

```
3.1.0-alpha01
```

Comment: I believe that should be enabled in Library B itself, but is "considered bad practice". So, either include both libs, or have/ask Library B to provide that dependency.

Comment: @Entreco thank you, do you have source that explains why its considered bad practice?

Comment: how do you include the library? with maven or locally? post your build.gradle files

Comment: I include A into B locally. I include A & B into my android app with Maven

Answer (score 4):

From comments if you need to use library **A** inside your *app* and your library **A** included into **B** using `implementation project(':LibA')`, then it won't be a transitive to your main *app*.

You have to include it into **B** using `api`, `api project(':LibA')`.

The `api` configuration should be used for dependencies that are exported to external modules (transitive dependency). Vice-Versa `implementation` configuration should be used for dependencies that are **internal to the component (not transitive dependency)**.

Answer (score 2):

That's called a transitive dependency.

Gradle, and all other dependency systems handle this automatically. If B needs A, you get A. If you are not getting A, that means B's dependencies are not correct.

Whether you should explicitly call out A in your dependencies is a debated topic. I'm of the camp that you should not. My reasoning is that you can end up with something like this,

```
include B(v1.0) -depends on-> A(1.0)
include A(1.1)
```

Now, which version of A gets compiled into your app and used at runtime? A 1.0 or A 1.1? The answer depends on the implementation of the build system.

- If it's A 1.0, then **YOU** are compiling against 1.1 but running against 1.0.
- If it's 1.1, then **B** is compiled against 1.0 but is using 1.1 at runtime.

Comment: I'm including A into B using  `implementation project(':LibA')`. Should I be including it differently?

Comment: If the platform you are running on does not provide `A` at runtime, then that's wrong. `implementation` means you compile against it but it's not packaged in your app, and you expect the platform (Android I assume in this case) to make it available.